# How to returne the last occurrence of a field using bash script in a file containing a JSON

Tags: bash, unix

Given the file containing this content:

```
{"CAMPOS":[{"CAMPO_ID":13071,"CAMPO_COD":"JJ1111-000","CAMPO_NAME":"Valor 1"},{"CAMPO_ID":13072,"CAMPO_COD":"JJ1111-004","CAMPO_NAME":"Valor2"},{"CAMPO_ID":13073,"CAMPO_COD":"JJ1111-01","CAMPO_NAME":"diversos valores"}, {"CAMPO_ID":13075,"CAMPO_COD":"JJ1111-02","CAMPO_NAME":"qualquer valor"}]}
```

How do I return the last occurrence of the CAMPO_ID value?

Comment: A crude way to achieve this might be: `sed 's/.*CAMPO_ID":\([[:digit:]]*\).*/\1 /' <<< $mystr`. But I guess there is CLI tools for parsing JSON. If somebody thinks this is worth an answer, I can make one out of my comment.

Comment: @Sidnei: You want this as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Use `jq` to process JSON files:

```
jq '.CAMPOS[-1].CAMPO_ID' file.json
```

The code is telling `jq` to select the value under the "CAMPOS" key, -1 means the last element in the array, and from it, it selects the CAMPO_ID key and returns its value.